# How to iterate multiple resources over the same list?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

New to Terraform here. I'm trying to create multiple projects (in Google Cloud) using Terraform. The problem is I've to execute multiple resources to completely set up a project. I tried `count`, but how can I tie multiple resources sequentially using `count`? Here are the following resources I need to execute per project:

1. Create project using `resource "google_project"`
2. Enable API service using `resource "google_project_service"`
3. Attach the service project to a host project using `resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project"` (I'm using shared VPC)

This works if I want to create a single project. But, if I pass a list of projects as input, how can I execute all the above resources for each project in that list sequentially?

Eg.

Input

```
project_list=["proj-1","proj-2"]
```

Execute the following sequentially:

```
resource "google-project" for "proj-1"
resource "google_project_service" for "proj-1"
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" for "proj-1"

resource "google-project" for "proj-2"
resource "google_project_service" for "proj-2"
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" for "proj-2"
```

I'm using Terraform version 0.11 which does not support `for` loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform, you can accomplish this using `count` and the two interpolation functions, `element()` and `length()`.

First, you'll give your module an input variable:

```tf
variable "project_list" {
  type = "list"
}
```

Then, you'll have something like:

```tf
resource "google_project" {
  count = "${length(var.project_list)}"
  name  = "${element(var.project_list, count.index)}"
}

resource "google_project_service" {
  count = "${length(var.project_list)}"
  name  = "${element(var.project_list, count.index)}"
}

resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" {
  count = "${length(var.project_list)}"
  name  = "${element(var.project_list, count.index)}"
}
```

And of course you'll have your other configuration in those resource declarations as well.

Note that this pattern is described in [Terraform Up and Running](https://www.terraformupandrunning.com), Chapter 5, and there are other examples of using `count.index` in the docs [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/resources.html).

Comment: if you think the answer is good and it works, why not vote it more than say thanks in comment?

Answer (score 0):

A small update to this question/answer (terraform 0.13 and above). The count or length is not advisable to use anymore due to the way that terraforms works, let's imagine the next scenario:

Suppose you have an array with 3 elements: `project_list=["proj-1","proj-2","proj-3"]`, once you apply that if you want to delete the `"proj-2"` item from your array once you run the plan, terraform will modify your second element to `"proj-3"` instead of removing It from the list [(more info in this good post)](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9). The solution to get the proper behavior is to use the [for_each](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/for-each) function as follow:

```
variable "project_list" {
  type = list(string)
}

resource "google_project" {
  for_each = toset(var.project_list)
  name  = each.value
}

resource "google_project_service" {
  for_each = toset(var.project_list)
  name  = each.value
}

resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" {
  for_each = toset(var.project_list)
  name  = each.value
}
```

Hope this helps!